# Pygame -> Moving a rect inside a class method

Tags: python, class, pygame

I have a class called Block, which I use to draw and move the block:

```
class Block:
    def __init__(self, pos_x, pos_y, size_x, size_y):
        self._posX = pos_x
        self._posY = pos_y
        self._sizeX = size_x
        self._r = pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, (200,100,100), (pos_x,pos_y,size_x,size_y), 0)

    def bMove(self, new_x, new_y):
        self._r.left = new_x
        self._r.top = new_y
```

Now, the draw part works great. The problem is I cant get the rectangle to move using the bMove class with ie. 'Box1.bMove(100, 100)'.
The code compiles withou any errors, but in the game no change to the rectangle happens.
Even using 'move(x,y)' or modifying the class to look like this:

```
class Block:
    def __init__(self, pos_x, pos_y, size_x, size_y):
        self._posX = pos_x
        self._posY = pos_y
        self._sizeX = size_x
        pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, (200,100,100), (pos_x,pos_y,size_x,size_y), 0)

    def bMove(self, new_x, new_y):
        self.left = new_x
        self.top = new_y
```

Didn't do any good.
Does anybody know how to fix this issue?
Any help would be gladly appreciated

Comment: You aren't drawing a rect inside the `bMove` method. `__init__` is called only once when you create an instance of the class.

Comment: So the proper way would be to draw it outside the init?

Comment: If you draw it inside the init, you can't move it, so yeah.

Comment: Could you show me a proper code modification as an answer, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`__init__` gets called only once, when you create an instance of a class.

You are trying to update the Block's position and draw it, so you need to have a method that can do that repeatedly.

```
class Block:
    def __init__(self, pos_x, pos_y, size_x, size_y):
        self._posX = pos_x
        self._posY = pos_y
        self._sizeX = size_x
        self._sizeY = size_y
        self._r = pygame.Rect(pos_x,pos_y,size_x,size_y)

    def bMove(self, new_x, new_y):
        self._r.left = new_x
        self._r.top = new_y

        pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, (200,100,100), self._r)
```

Here is some test code:

```
import pygame

pygame.init()

size = [640, 480]
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)
pygame.display.set_caption('Block')

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

class Block():
    def __init__(self, pos_x, pos_y, size_x, size_y):
        self._posX = pos_x
        self._posY = pos_y
        self._sizeX = size_x
        self._sizeY = size_y
        self._r = pygame.Rect(pos_x,pos_y,size_x,size_y)

    def bMove(self, new_x, new_y):
        self._r.left = new_x
        self._r.top = new_y

        pygame.draw.rect(screen, (200,100,100), self._r)

block = Block(0, 0, 50, 50)

done = False
while done == False:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done = True

    screen.fill((255, 255, 255))

    x, y = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    block.bMove(x, y)

    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(20)

pygame.quit()
```

Comment: Wouldnt this create a new instance of the rect everytime I'd like to move it?

Comment: Only if you do create an instance by calling Block() each time.

Comment: Thanks a milion :)